# on scala, how to wait for a Future.onFailure to complete?

Tags: scala

Scala futures:
With Await.result I can wait for the future to complete before terminating the program.

How can I wait for a Future.onFailure to complete before terminating the program?

```
package test

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Test5 extends App {
  def step(i: Int): Future[String] = Future {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    if (i == 3) throw new Exception("exception on t3")
    Thread.sleep(1000); val s = s"done: $i"; println(s); s
  }

  val task: Future[String] = step(1).flatMap(_ => step(2).flatMap(_ => step(3)))

  task.onFailure {
    case e: Throwable => println("task.onFailure. START: " + e); Thread.sleep(3000); println("task.onFailure. END.")
  }

  try {
    val result: String = Await.result(task, Duration.Inf)
    println("RESULT: " + result)
  } catch {
    case e: Throwable => println("Await.result.try catch: " + e)
  }

  // without this, "task.onFailure. END." does not get printed.
  // How can I replace this line with something such as Await.result([the task.onFailure I set previously])
  Thread.sleep(5000)  

  println("END")
}
```

Note: Instead of using `task.onFailure`, I could catch the exception on `Await.result` (as in the example). But I would prefer to use `task.onFailure`.

---

**Update**
A solution is to use `transform` or `recover` as proposed by Ryan. In my case, I needed something more, and I've added this alternative answer: [on scala, how to wait for a Future.onFailure to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495546/on-scala-how-to-wait-for-a-future-onfailure-to-complete/39508675#39508675)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is to sequence a side-effect such that you know that it has been executed I'd recommend using 'andThen'.

Answer (score 1):

`onFailure` returns `Unit`.  There's no way to block on that.

Either catch the exception on `Await.result` or use `transform` or `recover` to side-effect on the exception.

Comment: thanks, `transform` and `recover` helped me understand how to building this alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495546/on-scala-how-to-wait-for-a-future-onfailure-to-complete/39508675#39508675

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `Future#onFailure` returns `Unit` so there is no handle for which you can grab to block execution.

Since you're blocking on the completion of `task` *anyway*, the `catch` clause in your code is equivalent to what you would get from `onFailure`. That is, if the `Future` fails, the body of `catch` will be executed before the program exits because it is running on the main thread (whereas `onComplete` is not).

Comment: `onFailure` gets called when future fails with exception. you can wait on failing future for `onFailure` to get called

Comment: @pamu Waiting for the original future is not enough. The `onFailure` callback is scheduled asynchronously, which means that it can happen an arbitrary amount of time _after_ the original future has completed.

Answer (score 0):

We can enrich `Future` with `onComplete2` and `onCompleteWith2` as follows:

```
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future, Promise}
import scala.util.Try

object FutureUtils {
  implicit class RichFuture[T](val self: Future[T]) {
    def onComplete2[U](f: (Try[T]) => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
      val p = Promise[T]()
      self.onComplete { r: Try[T] => f(r); p.complete(r) }
      p.future
    }

    def onCompleteWith2[U](f: (Try[T]) => Future[U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
      val p = Promise[T]()
      self.onComplete { r: Try[T] => f(r).onComplete(_ => p.complete(r)) }
      p.future
    }    
  }
}
```

then I case use it as follows:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import FutureUtils._

import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

object Test5 extends App {
  def stepf(i: Int): Future[String] = Future { step(i) }

  def step(i: Int): String = {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    if (i == 3) throw new Exception("exception on t3")
    Thread.sleep(1000); val s = s"done: $i"; println(s); s
  }

  val task1: Future[String] =
    stepf(1).flatMap(_ => stepf(2).flatMap(_ => stepf(3)))

  // the result of step(10) and step(11) is ignored
  val task2: Future[String] = task1.onComplete2((r: Try[String]) => r match {
    case Success(s) => step(10)
    case Failure(e) => step(11)
  })

/*
  // If I want to recover (and so, to avoid an exception on Await.result:
  val task3 = task2.recover {case e: Throwable => step(12) }


  // I can use onCompleteWith2 instead of onComplete2
  val task2: Future[String] = task1.onCompleteWith2((r: Try[String]) => r match {
    case Success(s) => stepf(10)
    case Failure(e) => stepf(11)
  })
*/

  try {
    val result = Await.result(task2, Duration.Inf)
    println("RESULT: " + result)
  } catch {
    // see my comment above to remove this
    case e: Throwable => println("Await.result.try catch: " + e)
  }

  println("END.")
}
```

The execution is as follows:

```
done: 1
done: 2
done: 11
Await.result.try catch: java.lang.Exception: exception on t3
END.
```

If we don't throw the exception at `step(3)`, the execution is as follows. Note that RESULT is "done: 3", not "done: 10":

```
done: 1
done: 2
done: 3
done: 10
RESULT: done: 3
END.
```

Comment: as Viktor says, `future.andThen` is enough. It is similar to this `onComplete2` (using a `PartialFunction`). `onCompleteWith2` might still be useful to chain a `Future`.